# Windows Explorer Tooltip in WPF

Tags: wpf, windows, binding, tooltip, explorer

its not that hard what i want, but i'm pulling my hairs for days!

i just want the same tooltip behaviour like the WIndows Explorer:
overlay a partially hidden tree/list element with the tooltip that displays the full element

i use the following datatemplate in my treeview

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type TreeVM:SurveyorTreeViewItemViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children, Converter={StaticResource surveyorSortableCollectionViewConverter}}">
    <StackPanel x:Name="SurveyorStackPanel" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="20" Width="auto">
      ... (Textblocks, properties, usercontrol, border,... )                   
      <StackPanel.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip Placement="RelativePoint" Padding="0" HasDropShadow="False" 
               DataContext="{Binding ElementName=SurveyorStackPanel}">
                <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Width="{Binding ElementName=SurveyorStackPanel, Path=Width}"
                           Height="{Binding ElementName=SurveyorStackPanel, Path=Height}">
                     <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <VisualBrush AutoLayoutContent="True" AlignmentX="Left" 
                                     Visual="{Binding}" Stretch="None"/>
                     </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
           </ToolTip>
       </StackPanel.ToolTip>                                  
   </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

As you can see, i'm trying to use Visualbrush. but this doesnt work. it only shows what you see on the screen.

I have tried with static resource and binding on a new stackpanel thats in the tooltip, but that only leaves with a blanc tooltip.

Do i something wrong? do i have to use alternatives?
i'm pretty new in WPF. i know the basics, but binding/resources is kinda new for me

EDIT
here is the static source i tried:

```
<ToolTip x:Key="reflectingTooltip" DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" Placement="RelativePoint" Padding="0" HasDropShadow="False">
   <Rectangle Width="{Binding ActualWidth}" Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight}" Margin="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
      <Rectangle.Fill>
           <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding}" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left" />
      </Rectangle.Fill>
   </Rectangle>
</ToolTip>
```

EDIT 2

Here are a few pics from the situation i have now:
the whole element must be shown when tooltip shows.
 before tooltip: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg832/scaled.php?server=832&filename=beforedo.png&res=landing

when tooltip is shown: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg842/scaled.php?server=842&filename=afterbl.png&res=landing

tooltip has too large height and only shows what screens shows. only problem is to 'fiil in' the hidden text.

Comment: If you want a VisualBrush of your Stackpanel you may use `{Binding ElementName=SurveyorStackPanel}` but I would say thats not that you are searching for. So you may explain better what you exactly want to do. And are you sure that you want to have to VisualBrush. It just renders the visual you are binding to. So its some kind of a copy of the Visual just without a instance of a Visual in behind and also without all the eventhandler and so on. As example you can use it to create a mirror effect.

Comment: click on the links for example. i just want the same like Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

VisualBrush renders as a bitmap exactly the same thing you are providing by the 'Visual' property, and it does so without any modification to that thing: it renders them exactly as they are now.

If you want to display something else, you have to provide that something else.. Could you try with something like that: ?

```
<Window x:Class="UncutTooltip.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheText}"
                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                        </TextBlock>

                        <Grid.ToolTip>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheText}"
                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">
                            </TextBlock>
                        </Grid.ToolTip>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

        <Border Background="Red" >
            <TextBlock Margin="5" Foreground="WhiteSmoke" FontSize="18"
                       Text="The end of window:)" TextAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

---

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
namespace UncutTooltip
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new List<Item>
            {
                new Item { TheText = "its not that hard what i want, but i'm pulling my hairs for days!" },
                new Item { TheText = "i just want the same tooltip behaviour like the WIndows Explorer: overlay a partially hidden tree/list element with the tooltip that displays the full element" },
                new Item { TheText = "i use the following datatemplate in my treeview" },
                new Item { TheText = "As you can see, i'm trying to use Visualbrush. but this doesnt work. it only shows what you see on the screen." },
                new Item { TheText = "I have tried with static resource and binding on a new stackpanel thats in the tooltip, but that only leaves with a blanc tooltip." },
                new Item { TheText = "Do i something wrong? do i have to use alternatives? i'm pretty new in WPF. i know the basics, but binding/resources is kinda new for me" },
            };
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string TheText { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Edit:

Now, change the tooltip contents to i.e.:

```
                    <Grid.ToolTip>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TheWholeList}">
                            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                                    <!--<Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />-->
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheText}" />
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Grid.ToolTip>
```

and also change the data definition to:

```
public class Item
{
    public string TheText { get; set; }
    public IList<Item> TheWholeList { get; set; }
}

        var tmp = new List<Item>
        {
             .........
        };

        foreach (var it in tmp)
            it.TheWholeList = tmp;

        this.DataContext = tmp;
```

Note that I've commented out the width constraint in the tooltip's listbox, it will present an untruncated list of untruncated elements..

Edit #2:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource blah}">   // <---- HERE
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="250" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TheText}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />

                    <Grid.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip DataContext="{DynamicResource blah}">   // <---- HERE
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding [2].TheText}" />   // <---- just example of binding to a one specific item
                            <!-- <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">  another eaxmple: bind to whole list.. -->
                        </ToolTip>
                    </Grid.ToolTip>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>


public class Item
{
    public string TheText { get; set; }
}

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Resources["blah"] = new List<Item>   // <---- HERE
        {
            new Item { TheText = ........
             ........
```

In the last example, I've changed the window.DataContext binding, to a binding to a DynamicResource. In the window init, I've also changed the way the data is passed to the window. I've changed the tooltip template to include the Tooltip explicitely, and bound it to the same resource. This way, the inner tooltip's textblock is able to read the 3rd row of the datasource directly - this proves it is bound to the list, not to the Item.

However, this is crappy approach. It will work only with explicit Tooltip, only with Tooltip.DataContext=resource, and probably, it is the only working shape of such approach.. Probably it'd be possible to hack into the tooltip with attached behaviours and search it's parent window and get the bindings to work, but usually, it's not worth.. Could you try binding to the Item's properties like in the second sample?

Comment: I've fixed a typo:) You are effectively binding the Visual of VisualBrush to the `PlacementTarget` of the ToolTip. That is, you are ordering the Rectangle to render the element over which the ToolTip was displayed. This means that the Rectangle will look exactly the same as the underlying original control. This is not what you want, because the underlying element displays only non-hidden elements. You should have **another** control that looks like the original one, but that displays all elements, both hidden and non-hidded, and tren try binding the Visual to that full-list control instead..

Comment: OK, ty for feedback! any suggests which control i might use?

Comment: I've added a sample. Please note that the Visual proeprty is filled, not bound. If you will it with the same contents as the TreeView item template, then it will display the same. Then, bind it to the uncut data, and it will probably display in full. However, you can have problems with layouting the contents of the tooltip, as the VisualBrush "internal drawing area" does not necessarily have the same shape/dimensions as the target screen controls.. But first try that and see what it will show.

Comment: I've changed the code to the typical usage of a tooltip. Couldn't you do that this way? You can put anything in the tooltip, even a similar content to your item template. Look in the sample above - I've just added the TextBlock without any brushes and it stretched nicely to show  everything. The original textblock in the itemtemplate has less space, because it is limited by MaxWidth of the ListBoxItem (I set that up artificially for the purpose of example). You don't want to duplicate the XAML for item and tooltip, and tried to reuse it with VisualBrush? For this, there are other ways:)

Comment: the tooltip displays nothing :(

Comment: The complete code sample I've provided above displays empty tooltips?

Comment: indeed. 
fyi, it doesnt have to be the visualbrush. i just want a control that can bind the tooltips datacontext. visualbrush is the only one, as far as google search says :s

Comment: I've just copied the code of the above sample and pasted it into a project, run it, and it shows a window with a listbox with truncated items, and if you place cursor over an item - a tooltip pops up and shows whole text. Can you tell me how did you manage to make this sample to show empty tooltips? Did you run it in a new clean project?

Comment: Have you tried it with more than text? it will work with just text , but not if its with an image, a grid, a border, etc...
You directly bind with the Text property. wish if there is something i can do the same with a whole panel instead of a property of a control.. i mean a collection or a list of all the children of that panel :)

Comment: You can bind to anything. Look at my next edit - just for the sake of simplycity, I've added a list-ish field to the Item and I'm now binding it to a ListBox in the tooltip. The listbox shows everything correctly.

Comment: Please note that I'm all the time bind to the ITEM of the original list. Are you trying to tell me that you are unable to bind to the data that are OUTSIDE of your ITEM that has the tooltip? If so, then it is nearly impossible, as the tooltip is an another window that is given the DataContext=DATAITEM from the previous one, and as a new window it does not "see" any controls or outer scopes of the original frame..

Comment: yet another sample added, now with dynamic resources - I think this is what you tried to ask for. But beware, it is really cheap hack and it is likely to stop working if you modify its structure it too much (like, ie. moving DataContext={Dynamic...} to the TextBlock)